# How to make " #using <System.DLL>" work in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

How can I check if a process with a given name ("PowerPNT") is running?

After further web research, I've concluded that there is no Qt function which is able to do it :(, so I had to use a Win32 function, "GetProcessesByName" as described below.

```
#using <System.dll>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    ...
    if ( System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcessesByName( "PowerPNT" ).Length > 0 )
    {
        //Do something
    }
    ...
}
```

This does work for MSVC but unfortunately it doesn't for Qt:

> erreur : invalid preprocessing directive #using

I think that the problem is how to import the "System library" into Qt. I've looked around but no luck :( since I've never dealt with a DLL.

Is this feasible in Qt? If it is, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) which runs under .NET. You need plain C++ for your Qt project, presumably.

Comment: Boost should work with C++/CLI, it just won't run as managed. C++/CLI lets you used unmanaged C++ code in the same project as managed C++ code.

Comment: @Jonathan Gryspan: the problem is that QT is using a special pre processor called `moc` which cannot understand CLI. the `moc` generates vital additional source file that QT cannot work without.

Comment: David originally said boost for whatever reason; I was responding to that. :)

Comment: boost was inexplicable, sorry!

Comment: The moc could just ignore directive it doesn't understand. I'd rather assume the buildsystem isn't set up in a way to support managed code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, don't try and mix .NET and Qt. Instead use the native Win32 API for this : try the [EnumProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Take a look at this example :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623%28v=VS.85%29.aspx